# Running and saving the response in repeat API gatling which is to be used in the next exec call

Tags: gatling

I want to call an API in the exec for n number of times. Each time, I want to save the response. All the responses would be collectively passed in an array in the body in my next exec call.

Example
Let's say, I want to call upload Attachment API 5 times. The response of the API is in the following format.

```
{
  "attachmentId":"239092340ahds",
  "path":"abc/def"
}
```

After calling the above API 5 times, I want to use the response in the next exec call in the chain. The request body would look like this.

```
{
"data":[
{
  "attachmentId":"239092340ahds",
  "path":"abc/def"
},
{
  "attachmentId":"239092340ahds",
  "path":"abc/def"
},
{
  "attachmentId":"239092340ahds",
  "path":"abc/def"
},
{
  "attachmentId":"239092340ahds",
  "path":"abc/def"
},
{
  "attachmentId":"239092340ahds",
  "path":"abc/def"
}
]
}
```

How to achieve this in gatling?

Comment: I really recommend you go through the official documentation, including the tutorials, and the Gatling Academy. Your question is really about Gatling basics and you'll find all the answers you need in there.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. I did go through the doc and found a transform function which can be used to append the result in an existing variable and use it in the last exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the transform function. I got a variable from session. Appended the response to that variable and then saved it in the same variable.

```
.check(
      bodyString
        .transform((s, session) => {
          val response: String = session("response").as[String]
          if (!response.isBlank) {
            s + "," + response
          } else {
            s
          }
        })
        .saveAs("response")))
```